# Audio Not Playing Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm trying to play audio on a mouse enter event, but there's no audio playing. It works on Codepen (http://codepen.io/adamfaraj/pen/QpRjKL) but not when I import my code to Atom, it doesn't work.
Here's the Codepen code.

```
var nas_mp3 = $("#nasmp3")[0];
$("#nas")
.mouseenter(function() {
nas_mp3.play();
});
var nas_mp3 = $("#nasmp3")[0];
$("#nas")
.mouseout(function() {
nas_mp3.pause();
});
```

Here's what I have in Atom
HTML:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="audio.js" type ="text/javascript" ></script>

<div id="nas-container">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Nas-04.jpg/220px-Nas-04.jpg" id="nas">
<span id="nas-text">Nas</span>
</div>
<audio id="nasmp3" preload="auto">
<source src="https://old.undergroundhiphop.com/media/audios/320kbps/oldschool/Nas_Represent_OldSchool_320VBR.mp3"></source>
</audio>
```

Audio.js file:

```
var nas_mp3 = $("#nasmp3")[0];
$("#nas")
.mouseenter(function() {
nas_mp3.play();
});
var nas_mp3 = $("#nasmp3")[0];
$("#nas")
.mouseout(function() {
nas_mp3.pause();
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you imported the file correctly. Seems a typo in `<script src="audio.js"` whereas you say the file name is `Audio.js`. Also check if its in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

First solution:

```
    <div id="nas-container">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/70/Nas-04.jpg/220px-Nas-04.jpg" id="nas">
        <span id="nas-text">Nas</span>
        </div>
        <audio id="nasmp3" preload="auto">
        <source src="https://old.undergroundhiphop.com/media/audios/320kbps/oldschool/Nas_Represent_OldSchool_320VBR.mp3"></source>
        </audio>
<!-- Load all js in the end of document -->
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="audio.js" type ="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Second solution:

in your **audio.js** all your code put in

```
$(document).ready({
/*your code here*/
});
```

Third solution:
Put it in your **audio.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var nas_mp3 = document.getElementById('nasmp3');
    $('#nas').on('mouseenter',function(){
        nas_mp3.play();
    }).mouseout(function(){
        nas_mp3.pause();
    });
});
```

Enjoy.

Comment: that first solution worked. duh. script tags before closing body tag. i knew that....haha